# Is it a good idea to call already defined colors in color resource file?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-resources

I happen to use an SDK that has a few colors in color.xml defined as:

```
<color name="sdkTextColorPrimary">@android:color/white</color>
```

I was wondering if that's just extra code and makes the app larger in size by calling `android:color/white` and giving it your own name instead of calling R.color.white wherever we want to use it.

Comment: Yeah! There is no issue on this to call already defined colors.

Comment: yes ofcourse no issue with this approach.

Comment: I use this at least for code consistency and maintainability

Comment: @faran.javed alright, thanks!

Comment: @faran.javed - there ARE issues. See described post.

Comment: also have no idea who downvote post, that question is good and actual.

Answer (score 2):

Well its **bad** idea because some OEM androids sometimes replace default colors to something else.

For example when u use

```
@android:color/white
```

You expect that color will be `#ffffff`, but I met device where `@android:color/white` returned `#eeeeee`. Since you cannot predict that behaviour, much better decision is to use **only** your own colors.

For example Samsung Ace 4 for `@android:color/white` returnes `#f5f5f5`

Comment: That makes sense and is actually a great tip for another day. But what I meant was even if we define white as: <color name="actual_white">#ffffff</color>, is defining it again with a more specific name for a specific element for a better reference like <color name="icon_color">@android:color/actual_white</color> better?

Comment: if you are using a spectrum of colors that will set general theme of your app, then may be you can create constants for those colors and for specific controls you may reuse those colors as you mentioned. That is actually good in case you want to use themes or change colors later... its just matter of changing them at one place. Also you still have ability to test specific color for component if need be